# Random number pull from array MATLAB Poisson

Tags: python, matlab, random, poisson

This used to be simple in MATLAB and still it is in Python. I have an array of Lambdas that I am looking to produce Poisson distributed random numbers to insert into a histogram.

```
lambda = [0.1 0.4]
```

I used to be able to put in there:

```
n = poissrnd(a,10)
```

and get back an array of 10 rows by 2 columns of randomly generated Poisson numbers for each of the lambdas (each column representing 10 samples from each of the lambdas). For some reason, this has changed - and I'm not sure why.

In Python - this is still doable by just putting in:

```
n = np.random.poisson(lambda, [10,2])
```

I've been banging my head against the table - any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Welcome to the site! I assume you mean `lambda = [0.1 0.4]; n = poissrnd(lambda, 10)`. Out of curiosity, in which Matlab version did that work?

Comment: Sorry - yes. You are correct. n = poissrnd(lamda, 10). R2017b

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
N = 10;
lambda = [0.1 0.4];
```

- Without loop: from the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/poissrnd.html),

  > `R = poissrnd(lambda)` generates random numbers from the Poisson distribution with mean parameter `lambda`. `lambda` can be a vector, a matrix, or a multidimensional array. The size of `R` is the size of `lambda`.

  So:

  ```
  result = poissrnd(repmat(lambda, N, 1));
  ```
- With [`for`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop:

  ```
  result = NaN(N, numel(lambda)); % preallocate
  for k = 1:numel(lambda)
      result(:,k) = poissrnd(lambda(k), [N 1]);
  end
  ```
- With [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

  ```
  result = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) poissrnd(x, [N 1]), lambda, 'uniformoutput', false));
  ```

Comment: Thank you. The problem with the for loop is that I have a 3D array of varying lambdas that I am drawing from. Lets say that matrix is a 4 x 4 x 1000. If I want to sample that voxel 10e3 times, that is very time consuming with a for loop. Id rather just pull a 1 x 1 x 1000 vector, squeeze it, and, in one function call, sample it 10e3 times. Then run the four loop 15 more times (for the 4 x 4).